# Difference between C++ Keyboard keycode and JAVA KeyEvent keycode

Tags: java, c++, windows, keycode, keyevent

I noticed a difference between the keycodes that vkCode in C++ gives and the ones that Java's KeyEvent gives us. (Ofcourse the normal characters have the same code (0 => 48 just like the ASCII) but they differ in the other keys).
Is there a way to 'translate' them from one to the other (What's the logic behind each one?) or am I supposed to use loads of switches and IFs for that.
If it helps, my app is half in C++ and half in JAVA because of the Native Hooks that c++ gives us and it gets the keycodes of the keys that the user presses and then the java is going to use them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Standard C++ has no notion of anything called "vkCode" - perhaps you are thinking of some platform specific library? If so, please say which one.

Comment: Well yeh kind of. I am using windows.h and the vkCode is from here:
((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lparam)->vkCode //Suppose lparam is the LPARAM parameter that the hooks need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or am I supposed to use loads of switches and IFs

You can probably just put them in a [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table), that is, put the Java KeyCodes in a large array, so you just need to do `javaKeyCode = keyLut[cppScanCode]`.

One list of scan codes can be found [here](http://www.ee.bgu.ac.il/~microlab/MicroLab/Labs/ScanCodes.htm), and the `VK_KEYCODES` can of course be found in [the API docs for `KeyEvent`](http://72.5.124.55/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html).

Java is designed to be platform independent, so pressing the left-key for instance, will always yield a `VK_LEFT`, no matter scan code. I'm not entirely sure, but I suppose the C++-scancode is hardware dependent.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is my only hope. I havn't actually used the Lut before and the Netbeans IDE is telling me It's from the Java.Awt.Image. Is that the right one?

Comment: No no, lookup tables has nothing to do with the api. It's simply a way of encoding simple functions in as arrays.